# Passing data to another class in Python

Tags: python, oop

I am using Twisted and have a couple of callbacks, both of different types (so they don't share a factory).  I am trying to get data from one callback object to another:

```
class CallbackA(object):
  def transmit(self, data):
    self.sendMessage(self, data)

class CallbackB(object):
  def doRead(self): # this is called by Twisted
    self.point_to_A.transmit(self.point_to_A, data)

class bigClass(object):
  A = aClass
  B = bClass
  self.B.point_to_A = self.A
```

Now, I was able to get this to work by using `@staticmethod` before `transmit`.  Then I added the method (from twisted) `self.sendMessage`.  I got an error: 'global name self is not defined'.  Ok.  So I passed the object as the first argument like this:

```
self.point_to_A.transmit(self.point_to_A, data)
```

Then I get an error like this: 'unbound method sendMessage() must be called with 'class A' instance as first argument (got classobj instance instead)

So it seems I don't understand how to pass data to functions between sub-objects (objects instantiated under the same parent object); twisted callbacks in this case.

How can I call a function in child object 'A' from child object 'B', and pass data to that function, such that 'self' is available in that function in 'A' (as required by the Twisted method being used)?

**Edit:** Updated to show the 'self' references (as suggested in the comments), the error I get with the code as above is: unbound method sendMessage() must be called with `aClass` instance as a first argument (got classobj instance instead)

Comment: Add `self` to the class parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to the below code, essentially you need to remember:

1. To use the `self` keyword when creating object methods.
2. You need to either pass the `data` value as a method argument, or assign it somehow (see below).

Here is an example of how to pass data class-to-class:

```
class CallbackA(object):
    def transmit(self,data):  # See note 1
        do_stuff_with(data)   # See note 1

class CallbackB(object):
    def doRead(self,data):              # see note 1
        self.point_to_A.transmit(data)  # see note 2

class bigClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = CallbackA()
        self.B = CallbackB()
        self.B.point_to_A = self.A
```

the above code will probably not work verbatim but is an example of how you could pass data to another class in the way you describe.  You should be able to get yours working from this example.

And then when it is called:

```
test = bigClass()
test.B.doRead(data)
```

**Note 1:**  You need to declare the `data` somehow.  Either pass it as a method argument as I have shown, or you need to declare it as a property:

```
class CallbackA(object):
    def transmit(self,data):
        do_stuff_with(self.data)

class CallbackB(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def doRead(self):
        self.point_to_A.transmit(self.data)
```

or

```
class CallbackA(object):
    def transmit(self,data):
        do_stuff_with(self.data)

class ClassB(object):
    def set_data(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def doRead(self):
        self.point_to_A.transmit(self.data)
```

**Note 2:**  You either need to call the method as: `method(class_instance, args)` or `class_instance.method(args)`

**EDIT**

As an add-on to our discussion in comments.  Explicit declaration of `point_to_A`

```
 class ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self,A):
        self.point_to_A = A

    def set_data(self,data):
        self.data = data

    def doRead(self):
        self.point_to_A.transmit(self.data)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I implemented it like you showed (originally, before the alternative method shown in the second edit), but now I get this error: 'A instance has no __call__ method'.  Is that unrelated to what I'm trying to do with passing between classes?

Comment: I don't think it is related, that error in indicating there is some place in your code where something like `A.call(...)` is being called and it is complaining that there is not a method named `call`.  If you want to give me more info I could try and help though.

Comment: Well, I solved that unrelated error but... I have things set up as in your second example (right above Note 2), and I still get this: unbound method transmit() must be called with CallbackA as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: I changed it to explicitly declare point_to_A as in your most recent example.  I am getting the same error.  Isn't that error saying that transmit(data) will not work, and that the first argument to transmit() must be an object?  Edit in other words - your examples are the same as my setup.  But what does it mean that we are calling transmit as: transmit(self.data) (one argument) but declaring the function as: def transmit(self, data) (two arguments)?

Comment: When you call a class instances method as `self.point_to_A.transmit(self.data)` it passes `self.point_to_A` as the first argument and `self.data` as the second argument, which fits the method declaration `def transmit(self,data)`.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error you are receiving?  It can also be useful to add some print statements to see exactly where the code is failing, or use a [debugging tool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

Comment: Here is the error: exceptions.TypeError: unbound method transmit_ws() must be called with WSClientProto instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: @horsehair How about the context? What line is throwing the error?

Comment: I think I've made progress based on what you've helped me with.  Thank you very much.